# Lost in the woods

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Cleaning a cute rodent, or its inhabitation.
>   Overgrilled meat, or Justice Hugo's plantation.
>   Keeps us upright, or our prickly evergreenery.
>   Escape World War II, or blood thirsty insects' shady tree.

Comment: With the red herring of COKE as the first letters of each line...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the trick is

> for each line, the first half gives a two-word phrase where the second word starts with "s". For the second half, move the "s" to the end of the first word to give a new two-word phrase where the second word is a type of tree (hence, "lost in the woods").

However, I'm missing

> the trick to find the first words; e.g. I don't know how to pick a rodent for the first line.

The lines:

Cleaning a cute rodent, or its inhabitation.

> squirrel soak -> squirrel's oak

Overgrilled meat, or Justice Hugo's plantation.

> Black steak -> Black's teak

Keeps us upright, or our prickly evergreenery.

> Human spines -> Human's pines

Escape World War II, or blood thirsty insects' shady tree.

> Flee Selm -> Flea's elm

Comment: First is an animal that eats and bury's the tree's fruits.

Comment: Third is just a general (or loosely - medical) term. Note the "our" in the second part, which generally refers to us as a creation.